# Load custom CDN in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, cdn

I'm new in Angular 2 and I have a customized CDN to load some files in my Angular app. I'm loading this CDN in my `index.html` and all files are loading correctly, but it returns an error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function!
at module.exports (_a-function.js:2)
at module.exports (_ctx.js:4)
at _array-methods.js:24
at Array.map (es6.array.map.js:8)
at Array.toArray (prototype.js:1074)
at module.exports (_iter-define.js:39)
at Object.<anonymous> (es6.array.iterator.js:11)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d27006…:52)
at Object.<anonymous> (array.js:22)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d27006…:52)
```

Any idea about what's happening? Is it correct to load the CDN in `index.html`?

Thanks

Comment: try adding `defer` attribute on the script tag.

Comment: thanks, but if I use the `defer` attribute it works, but it doesn't load the files.

Answer (score 0):

You must think that Angular2 works with TypeScript rather than JavaScript so when you try to use those libs in the CDN from Angular2 project the compiler is probably not recognising the code.

By the way I'm also a newbie on Angular2, but I believe this could be the thing.

Comment: That's right, but in theory when you load your app in your `localhost:4200` the server compile the TypeScript to JavaScript (I'm using the CLI tool with the `ng serve`)